# Is it better to pass null or undefined to a component while data is being fetched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react app, I'm often fetching data from an API, which leaves some time where my components are not able to render data. From my research, I now understand that if you pass undefined, defaultProps will be used, but if you pass null, defaultProps is ignored.

The way my code is currently structured, I have defaultProps in a component, but its parent passes null while data is loading, so I'm null checking everything anyway.

Does it make more sense to manually be passing around undefined values to trigger defaultProps (in the context of fetching data)?

Also, does this also apply to my redux selectors (mapStateToProps)?

e.g.

```
<Component bedrooms={bedrooms || undefined} />
```

Comment: Note: I'm rarely ever using optional parameters. For the sake of this question, assume that every component prop is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep a prop say 'loading', of type boolean, which when true, would show a loader component and the actual component of bedrooms otherwise.

like:

```
<Component bedrooms={bedrooms} loading={bedrooms.length===0}/>
```

where

```
Component = ({bedrooms, loading})=> loading? <Loader/>: <div>bedrooms..</div>
```

also you can offload loading work to a HOC like

```
const withLoader = (Component)=>({loading, ...props})=>loading? <Loader/>: <Component {...props}/>
```

so, now

```
const withLoaderComponent = withLoader(Component);
```

usage `<withLoaderComponent {...props}/>`

Here Loader component can be any placeholder or a loading animation etc.

Further, with redux, we can move "loading" state to store, where, every onfetch action would set "loading" to true, and after fetchSuccess action will set it to false. Here, Loader can be a connected component also. So, Now we can have following decoupled structure.

```
<ConnectedLoader/><ConnectedComponent/>
```

where loading props of ConnectedLoader and props of ConnectedComponent, will be mapped to state of store with mapStateToProps/selectors

Comment: This is an interesting idea, it abstracts out a lot of the logic

Comment: I have a followup question about progressive loading. At first I made the whole page blank while loading. Then I started checking for null data in a component (e.g. a header) so that the header renders without any text. This made things quite cumbersome to work with. Would you use the same pattern (relying on an isLoading state) for this kind of progressive loading as well?

Comment: I guess to put it another way, is it safe to use this pattern and just assume that when not loading, all your objects are loaded? If so I could cut out a LOT of null checking code

Comment: you should put a loading variable for each fetch call related object in state, and inject it with component specific loading variable, with selectors, to each component, for progressive loading. yes you can rely on this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to use Javascript's null check.

```
{this.state.bedrooms && <Component bedrooms={this.state.bedrooms} />}
```

Another way is

```
{this.state.bedrooms ? <Component bedrooms={this.state.bedrooms} /> : null}
```

When React sees null, it will not render anything.